# How to import a picture from URL which is saved in database in existing data grid?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have been looking for solution for days now and still have done nothing. 
I have an database which, as one of the values has URL for picture, let´s say the attribute name is Picture_Link, I can show URL in data grid view but I have to show it as a picture with all other columns and rows. 
In other data grid I have to show pictures directly from link that I have from app-i result. 
All objects in data grid are shown via list which I import from data base (CRUD) and other one is via app-i key result.

```
            CRUD Video = new CRUD();
            List<YouTubeVideo> list = Video.GetVideosDB();
            dataGridYT.DataSource = list;
```

This is how my view is imported. 
Also I have some added columns, such as save and delete which are type image.

```
        DataGridViewImageColumn oSaveButton = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        oSaveButton.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/save.png");
        oSaveButton.Width = 50;
        oSaveButton.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridYT.Columns.Add(oSaveButton);
        dataGridYT.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

And CellContntClick functions which work. 
Everything works except dinamic upload of images in both of data grid views.

```
    private void dataGridYT_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
            {

                    if (dataGridYT.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Thumbnail")
                {
                    e.Value = GetImageFromUrl("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oZItXZtkmzg/default.jpg");
                    dataGridYT.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure;
                }
            }
 private object GetImageFromUrl(string url)
            {
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

                using (HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        return Image.FromStream(stream);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried this.

Still nothing, tried to make new data grid with only one column, have copied working code from repos and that one won´t work either. But if I make whole new solution it works. Added new column also.

I have tab control, with two tabs. Each tab has one data grid view, one of the columns shows values of image url´s which I have to use to show a picture, also I need that link for saving whole row in db. I have tried with foreach loop to get each cell value with link and to add image with function in code above.

Comment: Seems like something that someone would have already done. Google found some things, like: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/762435/how-to-add-pic-to-dataGridView-from-url

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work for me.

Comment: Nobody is answering your question because you show no attempt at research or solving it yourself. Now it sounds like you have an attempt, maybe you can edit your question to include something we can actually help with.

Comment: I get it, but I´m hopeless, my colleague is also trying but none of us is near solution.

Comment: OK, that's better but now we need to know specifically what doesn't work with your code. "got nothing" is not helpful, remember we cannot run your code, you have to tell us what is wrong.

Comment: No errors, no exceptions, runs as it should just that part is somehow missing. I have changed column type.

Comment: It works for me. Clone this repo and try it yourself: https://github.com/crowcoder/ImageColumnSample

Comment: it would be more easy to understand if you insert some code of your design View because there we can use a simpe <asp:imageField> to display an image

Comment: I´m using data source which is list made with function from custom made reference.

Comment: @Syed Munis Ali this is winforms

Comment: Still nothing, tried to make new data grid with only one column, have copied your code from repos and that one won´t work either.
But if I make whole new solution it works.
I have tab control, with two tabs. Each tab has one data grid view, one of the columns shows values of image url´s which I have to use to show a picture, also I need that link for saving whole row in db. 
I have tried with foreach loop to get each cell value with link and to add image with function in code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  dataGridYT.CellFormatting +=
       new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(
       this.dataGridYT_CellFormatting);
```

This line was missing and it fixed problems from above. I goes just under the code where I have added image cells such as oSaveButton.

```
 DataGridViewImageColumn oSaveButton = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        oSaveButton.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/YouTube_KV/save.png");
        oSaveButton.Width = 50;
        oSaveButton.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridYT.Columns.Add(oSaveButton);
        dataGridYT.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridYT.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridYT.Rows.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        dataGridYT.CellFormatting +=
       new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(
       this.dataGridYT_CellFormatting);

        dataGridYT.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```